# IPアドレスの集計を/24で行いたい

Tags: python, python3

集計したIPアドレスを第3オクテットでグループ化して集計したいです。

仮に集計したアドレスが送信元IPに記載されていれば、以下のように指定すれば集計できると思いますが、この方法だと逐一第三オクテットまで自分で記述しなければならず、煩雑だと考えます。

```
df.groupby("送信元IP"=="172.168.10.***").count()
```

他にどのような方法があるかご教示お願い致します。

なお、イメージとしては以下のような集計済みのデータに対して、第3オクテットでグループ化した集計を行いたいと考えております。

| 送信元IP | 宛先IP | 宛先ポート番号 | TCP/UDP | 合計 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.1.1.1 | 3.3.3.3 | 53 | 6 | 1 |
| 1.1.1.2 | 3.3.3.3 | 57 | 17 | 1 |
| 2.2.2.2 | 9.9.9.9 | 54 | 17 | 1 |
| 2.2.2.3 | 9.9.9.9 | 59 | 6 | 1 |
| 4.4.4.4 | 10.10.10.10 | 56 | 6 | 2 |

Comment: ipv6 とか考えないんですか？とかその辺が気になるっス。

Comment: 言葉足らずでした。今回はIPv6は対象外としています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 宛先Ipや宛先ポートのコラムを残して集計する

```py
import pandas as pd
import io

csv_data = '''
送信元IP,宛先IP,宛先ポート番号,TCP/UDP,合計
1.1.1.1,3.3.3.3,53,6,1
1.1.1.2,3.3.3.3,57,17,1
2.2.2.2,9.9.9.9,54,17,1
2.2.2.3,9.9.9.9,59,6,1
4.4.4.4,10.10.10.10,56,6,2
'''
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv_data))

#
df['「合計」列の総計値'] = df.groupby(df['送信元IP'].str.replace(r'\.\d+$', '', regex=True))['合計'].transform(sum)
print(df)
```

| 送信元IP | 宛先IP | 宛先ポート番号 | TCP/UDP | 合計 | 「合計」列の総計値 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.1.1.1 | 3.3.3.3 | 53 | 6 | 1 | 2 |
| 1.1.1.2 | 3.3.3.3 | 57 | 17 | 1 | 2 |
| 2.2.2.2 | 9.9.9.9 | 54 | 17 | 1 | 2 |
| 2.2.2.3 | 9.9.9.9 | 59 | 6 | 1 | 2 |
| 4.4.4.4 | 10.10.10.10 | 56 | 6 | 2 | 2 |

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。今回、送信元IP、宛先IP、宛先ポート、合計の変数名を作成し、集計しているのですが、送信元IPでグループ化してカウントするには、

Comment: 送信元IP 以外の列があっても結果は同じになります。

Comment: 集計の部分は、送信IPをグループ化後の値で集計したいと考えています。

Comment: 上記の回答は送信元IPをグループ化した後に集計しています。結果が期待しているものとは異なる場合には、質問文に期待する結果を追記してみてください。

Comment: 宛先Ipや宛先ポートのコラムを残して集計することは可能でしょうか。

Comment: 「カラムを残して集計する」というのは矛盾していますが。。。まぁ、字面としては可能でしょうけれども。

Comment: 送信元IPをグループ化した状態で、dfx=df.groupby(df.columns.tolist()[:-1],as_index=False).agg({“合計”:”sum”}で集計できれば良いのですが、groupbyしている状態で更にgroupbyはできないので、妙案はないかと思った次第です

Comment: 一応書き直してみました。

Comment: ご教示ありがとうございます。